# Numbers spreadsheet can't be imported

Tags: macos, ios, numbers

I have a spreadsheet I have been updating in IOS Numbers for several months and I sometimes update it with OSX Numbers

However when I did a recent update in OSX I get the error message `Spreadsheet couldn't be imported. An error occurred` when I tried to open in IOS. This as the first time I edited in OSX since the iPhone was upgraded to IOS7.

I have edited the spreadsheet down so that it is just a simple table - to make sure that my recent edits had not caused an incompatibility.

I have looked at the problem spreadsheet in iCloud and it seems OK.
I also got a backup via Time Machine on OSX of before I opened it in OSX and that is openable in IOS

The errors Occur with Numbers '09 2.3(554) on OSX 10.8.5 and Numbers on IOS 7.0.2

How can I find out what is causing the error (and then fix it)

Comment: What version / OS combination now works and what fails? Did you try logging into http://iCloud.com to see if the file is corrupt in the cloud store?

Comment: Why the -ve downvote - the question is how do I debug it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
A hard reset of my iPad (press and hold both the home button and the power button until the device turns off, then wait while it reboots) solved the issue.

Answer (score -3):

Also I have had the same problem and had to convert the file for it to work. See my workaround [here](https://sites.google.com/site/iphonetipsandsecrets/home/numbers-problem).
Hope this works for you too. :)

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Comment: @Jason  The link is broken